# How to get UTC stored date results with condition of specific timezone

Tags: php, mysql, timezone, utc

We have stored date data type in UTC format. Here every user has there own time one. I am saving my events dates and times as below

```
| Eventname | createddate | start time | endtime  |
| Test      | 2017-06-01  | 12:00:0 0  | 16:00:00 |
```

Createddate data type is date.
Start time and endtimes data type is time.
Above date and times are stored in UTC time one.

Now user timezone is GMT+13
So above event will display on 2017-06-02 date for user.so how to get results using MySQL?

If I search results on 02nd date above result should come.

Please suggest me how to get UTC results based on user specified timezone

Answer (score 0):

You could use MYSQL [CONVERT_TZ](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz)

In your search criteria, convert your client timezone to the UTC using this function.

Comment: Oh we can use in where condition?

Comment: Yes, but if you need the time to be retrieved the date in expected timezone, use in select columns with an alias.